# SQL pivot without dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I want to use pivot in my sql query with dynamic pivot columns but I do not want to use dynamic sql query and then execute that. As my requirement is to store the result to a temporary table .

Is there a way to use dynamic column in pivot for clause without dynamically creating the query ?

or

If I am preparing the query dynamically, Is there a way to store the result into temporary table ?

Please suggest something.

Comment: If you want a dynamic number of columns as a result, then you'll need dynamic SQL

Comment: If the columns are unknown, then you **have** to use dynamic SQL.  There is no other way around that.  PIVOT requires the columns to be known, so you'll have to create a sql string ahead of time and then execute it.

Comment: ok, Is there a way to store the result in temp table ?

Comment: So you need a dynamic temp table? Do a select into #tempTable {dynamic query} and in the where clause say 1=2 so no records are populated and the temp table is built with the relevant columns

Comment: can you write me the query please?

to work for now I am not creating a temp table but a real table in db with a dynamic name (using NEWID()) and when I am done with data  I need I drop that table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. I am using a stored procedure. The main source table DeptBudget has various columns such as user, date, etc, bu the columns I am using are Status, HR_Budget and    IT_Budget. I am using 9 possible status but could be modified for more. The best part is that I dont have to know the values for the statuses! The solution key is to use and Identity as the pivot fields, then rename columns and drop as needed. No dynamic SQL needed!

```
-- STEP 1: Declare Column Name Variable
Declare @tnc varchar(50)

-- STEP 2: Create 2 temporay tables #StageA and #StageB.
CREATE TABLE #StageA (
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Budget varchar(50), 
HR_Budget decimal(12,2),
IT_Budget decimal(12,2)
)
CREATE TABLE #StageB (
Budget varchar(50), 
[1] decimal(12,2),
[2] decimal(12,2),
[3] decimal(12,2),
[4] decimal(12,2),
[5] decimal(12,2),
[6] decimal(12,2),
[7] decimal(12,2),
[8] decimal(12,2),
[9] decimal(12,2)
)

-- STEP 3: Dump Aggregated data into #StageA
INsert Into #StageA (Budget, HR_Budget, IT_Budget)
Select [Status], Sum(HR_Budget), Sum(IT_Budget)
From DeptBudget
Group By [Status]


-- STEP 4: Pivot into #StageB
Insert into #StageB
    Select Budget,  SUM([1]) AS [1],SUM([2]) AS [2],SUM([3]) AS [3],SUM([4]) AS [4],SUM([5]) AS [5],SUM([6]) AS [6]
    ,SUM([7]) AS [7],SUM([8]) AS [8],SUM([9]) AS [9]
    from
    (
    Select   'IT Budget' As Budget,  ISNULL([1], 0) AS [1],ISNULL([2], 0) AS [2],ISNULL([3], 0) AS [3],ISNULL([4], 0) AS [4],ISNULL([5], 0) AS [5],ISNULL([6], 0) AS [6]
        ,ISNULL([7], 0) AS [7],ISNULL([8], 0) AS [8],ISNULL([9], 0) AS [9]
    from
        (
        Select ID, IT_Budget From #StageA 
                )
        pvt
        Pivot
        (
            Sum(IT_Budget) for [ID] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])
        )   
    Pvttab   
Union
    Select   'HR Budget' As Budget,  ISNULL([1], 0) AS [1],ISNULL([2], 0) AS [2],ISNULL([3], 0) AS [3],ISNULL([4], 0) AS [4],ISNULL([5], 0) AS [5],ISNULL([6], 0) AS [6]
        ,ISNULL([7], 0) AS [7],ISNULL([8], 0) AS [8],ISNULL([9], 0) AS [9]
    from
    (
    Select ID, HR_Budget From #StageA
                )
        pvt
        Pivot
        (
            Sum(HR_Budget) for [ID] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])
        )
        Pvttab   

Union
    Select   'Total Budget' As Budget,  ISNULL([1], 0) AS [1],ISNULL([2], 0) AS [2],ISNULL([3], 0) AS [3],ISNULL([4], 0) AS [4],ISNULL([5], 0) AS [5],ISNULL([6], 0) AS [6]
        ,ISNULL([7], 0) AS [7],ISNULL([8], 0) AS [8],ISNULL([9], 0) AS [9]
    from
    (
    Select ID, HR_Budget + IT_Budget AS BudgetTotal  From #StageA
    )
    pvt
    Pivot
    (
    Sum(BudgetTotal) for [ID] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])
    )
    Pvttab   

) pVS
Group By Budget 

-- STEP 5: Rename The Columns and drop those not needed.
select @tnc  = Null
Select @tnc = Budget From #StageA Where ID=1
If @tnc IS Not NUll 
    Begin
        EXEC tempdb..sp_rename '#StageB.[1]', @tnc, 'COLUMN'
    End
    Else
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE #StageB
        DROP COLUMN  [1];       
    End
select @tnc  = Null
Select @tnc = Budget From #StageA Where ID=2
If @tnc IS Not NUll 
    Begin
        EXEC tempdb..sp_rename '#StageB.[2]', @tnc, 'COLUMN'
    End
    Else
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE #StageB
        DROP COLUMN  [2];       
    End

select @tnc  = Null
Select @tnc = Budget From #StageA Where ID=3
If @tnc IS Not NUll 
    Begin
        EXEC tempdb..sp_rename '#StageB.[3]', @tnc, 'COLUMN'
    End
    Else
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE #StageB
        DROP COLUMN  [3];       
    End

select @tnc  = Null
Select @tnc = Budget From #StageA Where ID=4
If @tnc IS Not NUll 
    Begin
        EXEC tempdb..sp_rename '#StageB.[4]', @tnc, 'COLUMN'
    End
    Else
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE #StageB
        DROP COLUMN  [4];       
    End

select @tnc  = Null
Select @tnc = Budget From #StageA Where ID=5
If @tnc IS Not NUll 
    Begin
        EXEC tempdb..sp_rename '#StageB.[5]', @tnc, 'COLUMN'
    End
    Else
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE #StageB
        DROP COLUMN  [5];       
    End

select @tnc  = Null
Select @tnc = Budget From #StageA Where ID=6
If @tnc IS Not NUll 
    Begin
        EXEC tempdb..sp_rename '#StageB.[6]', @tnc, 'COLUMN'
    End
    Else
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE #StageB
        DROP COLUMN  [6];       
    End

select @tnc  = Null
Select @tnc = Budget From #StageA Where ID=7
If @tnc IS Not NUll 
    Begin
        EXEC tempdb..sp_rename '#StageB.[7]', @tnc, 'COLUMN'
    End
    Else
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE #StageB
        DROP COLUMN  [7];       
    End

select @tnc  = Null
Select @tnc = Budget From #StageA Where ID=8
if @tnc IS Not NUll
    Begin
        EXEC tempdb..sp_rename '#StageB.[8]', @tnc, 'COLUMN'
    End
    Else
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE #StageB
        DROP COLUMN  [8];       
    End

select @tnc  = Null
Select @tnc = Budget From #StageA Where ID=9
If @tnc IS Not NUll 
    Begin
        EXEC tempdb..sp_rename '#StageB.[9]', @tnc, 'COLUMN'
    End
    Else
    Begin
        ALTER TABLE #StageB
        DROP COLUMN  [9];       
    End


-- Show The Data
Select * From #StageB
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can store into tmp table by select ..into..statement

Thanks

Comment: It's not that simple when using dynamic SQL though, at least if he wants to reuse that temp table

Comment: yes, @Lamak is right I tried this and that did not work.